# Increase rendering speed in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I am building a flash application ,am running the app in .net form using the official adobe plugin. it takes huge memory and CPU,  i am wondering why the flash is still laggy.

I have set `wmode=gpu` but still am not getting a smooth play.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you expect an answer to this question to look like?   Like any program on any platform made with any language, it's performance can depend a ton of different things.  Without seeing the code, and knowing the nature of the application, no one can tell you why it's slow.

Comment: It really depends on the app. This article might be useful http://www.craftymind.com/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/

Comment: wmode=gpu does not work on desktop (if you use it), only on mobile http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html. On desktop it fallback to `direct`

Comment: Using `wmode=gpu` will not fix any bad code for you. Make sure everything is optimized before you output the SWF. Also remember anything loaded by Flash goes into memory (=huge RAM usage if careless). You might also have code that keeps the CPU overworking... In other words, **any hints about the nature of your SWF might help us to help you**... (is there an `enter_frame` event & what does its code do? Are you importing large assets into your app's allocated memory space? etc etc etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating Flash Player ! that might have been an issue , if you are using .net form , then update the flash player of IE so that it will be updated in the form !